# AudioStreaming mic to RTP server using java

Tags: java, sockets, audio-streaming, rtp, microphone

I'd like to stream my microphone live to an rtp server which spread the stream to other clients.

It looks like someone tried this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122097/live-audio-stream-java) 2 years ago. I tested the Client.java and Server.java, but the described problem in his Client.java still exists, no working microphone.

**Client.java from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122097/live-audio-stream-java):**

```
Client:

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class Mic 
{
    public byte[] buffer;
    private int port;
    static AudioInputStream ais;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TargetDataLine line;
        DatagramPacket dgp; 

        AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
        float rate = 44100.0f;
        int channels = 2;
        int sampleSize = 16;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        InetAddress addr;


        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(encoding, rate, sampleSize, channels, (sampleSize / 8) * channels, rate, bigEndian);

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line matching " + info + " not supported.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            int buffsize = line.getBufferSize()/5;
            buffsize += 512; 

            line.open(format);

            line.start();   

            int numBytesRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[buffsize];

            addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            while (true) {
                   // Read the next chunk of data from the TargetDataLine.
                   numBytesRead =  line.read(data, 0, data.length);
                   // Save this chunk of data.
                   dgp = new DatagramPacket (data,data.length,addr,50005);

                   socket.send(dgp);
                }

        }catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

I found that someone else got an working microphone client here, but it's just for local playback. What's the difference there so the microphone is working? I am new to java and cannot figure it out actually.

**Client for playback from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798200/java-record-mic-to-byte-array-and-play-sound):**

```
package audio;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class AudioTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000.0f, 16, 1, true, true);
        TargetDataLine microphone;
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
        SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
        try {
            microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            microphone.open(format);

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int numBytesRead;
            int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
            byte[] data = new byte[microphone.getBufferSize() / 5];
            microphone.start();

            int bytesRead = 0;

            try {
                while (bytesRead < 100000) { // Just so I can test if recording
                                                // my mic works...
                    numBytesRead = microphone.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
                    bytesRead = bytesRead + numBytesRead;
                    System.out.println(bytesRead);
                    out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte audioData[] = out.toByteArray();
            // Get an input stream on the byte array
            // containing the data
            InputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    audioData);
            audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(byteArrayInputStream,format, audioData.length / format.getFrameSize());
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            sourceDataLine.open(format);
            sourceDataLine.start();
            int cnt = 0;
            byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];
            try {
                while ((cnt = audioInputStream.read(tempBuffer, 0,tempBuffer.length)) != -1) {
                    if (cnt > 0) {
                        // Write data to the internal buffer of
                        // the data line where it will be
                        // delivered to the speaker.
                        sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                    }// end if
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Block and wait for internal buffer of the
            // data line to empty.
            sourceDataLine.drain();
            sourceDataLine.close();
            microphone.close();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing the audio format is different between the two.  In the first, it's CD quality stereo (44khz, 2 channels) and the second it's voice quality mono (8khz, 1 channel.)

Comment: I don't think that's the point, do you?

Comment: OP asked "What's different?"  I provided an answer.