# Java Client-Server: Stream audio files in real time

Tags: java, file, sockets, audio, streaming

Im making a client-server based music applicationn like spotify.The following is a only simple part of code that sends an `mp3 audio file` to my client. What i want is to **play this .mp3 audio file to my client in real time**
What to change in order to achieve this?

Edit : i have watched a lot of similar post both here on stackoverflow and GitHub but i cant find any solution

Server

```
public void send_file_to_client(String requested_file) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;

        File FILE_TO_SEND = new File("C:\\ServerMusicStorage\\" + requested_file + ".mp3");
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) FILE_TO_SEND.length()];
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_TO_SEND);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        OutputStream os = null;
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os = connsock.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Sending " + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
    }
```

Client

```
public static void receive_file_from_server(String requested_file) throws IOException {

        File file_to_save = new File("C:\\ClientMusicStorage\\" + requested_file + ".mp3");
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[FILE_SIZE];
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file_to_save);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        current = bytesRead;

        do {
            bytesRead
                    = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                current += bytesRead;
            }
        } while (bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
        bos.flush();
        System.out.println("File " + requested_file + ".mp3"
                + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");

    }
```

Comment: Check this thread on Stack Overflow:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122097/live-audio-stream-java

Comment: @fr3ddie thank you, i have already saw it . As i mentioned  i have watched a lot of similar post both here on stackoverflow and GitHub but none helped me.

Comment: Is the issue that streaming PCM bytes works but streaming compressed audio isn't working?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you indicated in what regard the cited post didn't help.